# I want to use inline for loop in the following way

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

anyone please correct me in writing for loop in Django template , see below code to understand what im trying to do

```
{% for item in items and for quantity in quantities %}
```

here is my views.py

```
def addtocart(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    items = []
    quantity = []
    for item in MenuModel.objects.all():
        if int(request.POST[str(item.id)])!=0:
            items.append(item.item_name)
            quantity.append(request.POST[str(item.id)])
    context = {'items' : items, 'quantities' : quantity}
return render(request,"gupsupapp/checkout.html",context)
```

Comment: why don't use two separate for loops?

Comment: I want to print item and quantity on same line, I can't do that with separate for loops

Comment: {% for item in items %}
{% for quantity in quantities %}
<H1>{{ item }} - {{ quantity }}</H!>

Comment: @TiagoGomes, it is not going to work. it will display all quantities for each item

Comment: so the concept of your loop is wrong. items and quantities are objects? how they are linked to each other?

Comment: @TiagoGomes items and quantities are list sent into the context and then to the render function

Comment: If I understood, you are trying to link lists using the position of elements. Post an answer that could help. But, is it possible to change the elements before they arrive in template? like, create an object, or a list of tuples in the format you want?

Comment: @PAVANKUMAR Are you looking for something like `zip` does in python?

Comment: @mohammedwazeem im new to python, I dunno what's meant by zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understood correctly, but try this:

```
def addtocart(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        items = {}
        for item in MenuModel.objects.all():
            if int(request.POST[str(item.id)])!=0:
                items[item.id] = {
                    "name": item.item_name,
                    "quantity": request.POST[str(item.id)])
                }
        context = {"items": items}

   return render(request,"gupsupapp/checkout.html",context)
```

then on template:

```
{% for key, item in items.items %} 
    {{item.name}}-{{item.quantity}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: how quantity will work if there is no term quantities. quantities is a list sent to the template via context.

Comment: edit your question to add sample data, and sample output, please?

Comment: dictionary has no such attribute append

Comment: sorry, edited... but, try to understand the concept before copy and paste the code

Comment: yes im trying on my own, but I just want to intimate the error I got if I use your code

Comment: can u clarify what is items.items? and explain the total code if possible

Comment: https://www.gun.io/blog/how-to-list-items-in-a-dictionary-in-a-django-template

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
{% for item in items %} 
    {% for quantity in quantities %}

        {{ item }} - {{ quantity }}

    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: this is not going to work, it will print multiple quantities for the same item

Comment: @PAVANKUMAR Can you please throw in some sample data and expected output. I will check it.

Comment: I don't know how to post images here @Mayank Porwal

Comment: Don't put images. Paste some sample datain code format in your question with expected output.

Comment: I added views.py file.  if I follow ur code im getting pizza 3 burger 3 pizza 1 burger 1. but the output I need is pizza 3 burger 1